# Why GUI Component in Qt5 shows different sizes when deployed on system with different resolution

Tags: qt5, screen-resolution, qt-designer

I am developing an application in Qt5. when I deployed it on the machine on which it is developed it looks fine. But when I deployed it on laptop with higher resolution, the size of components like QPushButtons etc,reduces.Please help me, I have no idea why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you specifying the size but, maybe you are using fixed sizes? If so, when deploying on a higher resolution display the interface is apparently smaller but in fact has the same size than in the smaller resolution display.

Try using relative sizes or at list show how you are setting the size right now

Comment: Initially I used the fixed sizes in pixel. But I removed it. Still the QPushButtons sizes are reducing when deployed on higher resolution laptop